Is Jacobian $Pic^0(X_t)$ invariant in some sense for some good family?
The Jacobian $\operatorname{Pic}^0(Y)$ of a complex manifold $Y$ is defined to be    the kernel of the map $\operatorname{Pic}(Y) \rightarrow H^2(Y, \mathbb{Z})$ and it is an abelian variety of dimension $h^{0,1}(Y)$ when $Y$ is a projective manifold.
Let $X\to S$ be a smooth morphism (or say family) with each fiber projective. Then as is well-known, the Hodge number $h^{0,1}(X_t)$ is invariant. So at least the dimension of $\operatorname{Pic}^0(X_t)$ is invariant.
Question:   Is the Jacobian $Pic^0(X_t)$ of fiber  invariant in some sense? For example, is $Pic^0(X_t)$ biholomorphic (homeomorphic  or diffeomorphic) to each other? Is the foundamental group of $Pic^0(X_t)$ has some deformation properties? etc.

The varieties $Pic^0(X_t)$ are dependent of the choice of fiber. For an example, the Torelli Theorem says that a smooth complex curve is determined by its Jacobian, so it is easy to come up with families of smooth curves where the Jacobians of the fibers are not isomorphic.
What is true is that given a smooth family $X \rightarrow S$, there is a smooth family $Pic^0_{X/S} \rightarrow S$ whose fiber at a point $t \in S$ is $Pic^0(X_t)$. In other words, the Jacobians vary smoothly as the manifold varies. For a precise statement, see Proposition 5.20 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504020
Because the $Pic^0(X_t)$ are in a smooth family, they will all be diffeomorphic and have the same fundamental group, although this also follows from the fact that they are all complex tori of the same dimension.

The Jacobians of the fibers in the family are certainly equidimensional (and therefore diffeomorphic, since all complex tori of the same dimension are diffeomorphic), but they are not biholomorphic to each other in general. For example, if the fibers are Riemann surfaces, the biholomorphism class of the Jacobian determines the biholomorphism class of the fiber.
